# Статическая линковка Python

Tags: c++, python, dll, lib

Передо мной стоит задача: есть некоторый python скрипт, его необходимо использовать в DLL, при этом максимально минимизировать количество выходных файлов (желательно до одной dll).

Итак, сам python скрипт загружен в ресурсы проекта и выполняется с помощью Python/C API. Следующим шагом, хотелось бы интегрировать интерпретатор python в мою dll.

Для этого:

- Скачаны исходники("Решение") Python 2.7.11 с официального сайта
- Для компиляции выбран один проект - pythoncore
- Тип конфигурации изменен с DLL (динамическая библиотека) на LIB (статическая   библиотека)
- Получившийся LIB файл добавлен в зависимости моего проекта

Насколько мне известно, при компиляции моего проекта, статически прилинкованные библиотеки должны экспортировать свой код в прилинковавшую его библиотеку. Соответственно этот LIB файл (~15Mb!) полностью самодостаточный (как я понимаю).

Но при компиляции моего проекта я получаю ошибки:

> Ошибка    3   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ
>   __imp__Py_Initialize в функции _main  E:\7zip\myprogtamm\myprogtamm\main.obj

Объявление и исходный код этой функции присутствует в проекте - pythoncore.
В чем может быть причина?

Comment: есть 2 уточнения - указан ли путь к получившемуся .lib файлу? имеют ли .lib и ваш проект одинаковую разрядность (x86/x64)?

Comment: Да, проект видит .lib файл. Оба проекта имеют платформу решения "Win32".